# Facebook Access Token Invalid for search endpoint

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am making this request through graph api and i am getting this error:

```
(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint
```

A couple of days ago i was making the same requests without any problem and now i keep getting this error messages, i don't know why. the query i am requesting is the following:

`/search?q=SOMETHING&type=event&fields=id,name,description,cover,start_time,end_time,location,owner,venue&limit=5000&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`.

This query works on graph api explorer (including the access token). My question is, the error is mine or from facebook?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the Access Token in the Debugger and check if it´s valid: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

If yes, file a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/